# Paypal error - getTransactionFee method does not exist

Tags: php, paypal

I have a custom website with a custom shopping cart built in. I am using the Paypal API Standard Payments method to send the shopping cart information over to Paypal & then returning on a return URL to my order_process.php page. Once it returns to my website, the code updates information in our database to sign members up for events, give them a membership etc.

Everything was working fine until Paypal flagged our account due to the high increase in payments coming in within a short period of time.

I spoke with a supervisor over at Paypal & they lifted the flag from our account.

We did not change anything on our end but now the site is not working properly anymore. It sends the information over to Paypal, takes the payment successfully & comes back to our site.

Once it gets to the line in code

```
$result = execute_payment($_SESSION["payment_id"], $_GET["PayerID"]);
```

It crashes with an error: "Method PayPal\Api\Sale::getTransactionFee() does not exist"

I've spoken to Paypal numerous times and they keep saying they will call me back with no return phone calls. I've extensively Googled this error and cannot find anything on this topic. I'm at a lost of what to try next and this is causing a lot of disruption because we are processing a high amount of transactions. I switched the site over to a development domain and tried on Sandbox mode and am still receiving the same error message.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't really do much with that limited code provided. Do you still have your include for the `Paypal\Api\Sale` intact? Sounds like someone buggered that class or it is no longer referenced. PHP error logs mention the missing reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our site has just started displaying this behaviour too, I don't understand what is going on. It was working perfectly this time last week.

Maybe there is a new version of the PayPal PHP SDK I need to download!?!?

Help!

-- UPDATE: found this on the PHP SDK wiki: "Seeing this error: 'Method PayPal\Api\Sale::getTransactionFee() does not exist' in paypal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PPReflectionUtil.php:73, Please upgrade the SDK to latest version v1.2.1."

See https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki

I've downloaded the new SDK and am integrating it now. Will update when done ...

-- Another Update: Updated our test site to use version 1.2.1 of PHP SDK, and everything works fine against the sandbox. Not sure which language/SDK you're using, but might be worth an update?

Comment: Glad to hear I'm not the only one in this boat! Hopefully this thread will provide us with a solution.

Comment: @Chris This response is perfectly fine, but it really belongs in Comments under the OP.  "Me to" answers are generally discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently updating will let you know the outcome once I'm finished.

Comment: Just updated to version 1.2.1 and it works! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Updating to v1.2.1 would fix this issue. A bug was found that was causing the new payment object to be not gracefully handled, and that caused the breakage. Apologies for a short notice, as it was not caught during the integration test before. However, this has been fixed now, and SDK is made to handle such issues in future without breaking current integrations.

Comment: Same thing here, upgrading the systems now...but wow, what a lesson on BC :(

Comment: I've updated from 0.16 to 1.3 and it works. But watch out when upgrading from version below 1.0 as it changes file structure and some method names - https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Breaking-Changes---1.0.0

Comment: @JayPatel-PayPal for a product offering financial services, it really seems unstable, especially when you're breaking other companies production level code. It's hard to trust you guys when you pull stunts like this. Also, you shouldn't be changing method names and class names (including exceptions). They should be deprecated gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke with an engineer over at Paypal. Apparently they updated some of their code and are aware of this issue. They are currently working on a fix to the problem.

Comment: Super, I just love when third party providers break production code, and are "working" on it for over a week.

Comment: Hey @Beachhouse ! We released the newer version of SDK that fixes the issues on the same day we found the issue. You could please look at the comment below: 
Updating to [v1.3.1](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/releases) would fix this issue. A bug was found that was causing the new payment object to be not gracefully handled, and that caused the breakage. Apologies for a short notice, as it was not caught during the integration test before. However, this has been fixed now, and SDK is made to handle such issues in future without breaking current integrations.